# How important is the JWKS endpoint in OpenID Connect?

Tags: openid-connect

Our security is changing, so I'm updating an Angular SPA application to use OpenID Connect. I found a nice [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-auth-oidc-client) to help set things up. However, I've run into an issue where it tries to access the JWKS endpoint unsuccessfully; it's blocked by CORS even though my application has been whitelisted.

Neither I nor my cyber security counterparts are able to explain the issue. Please assume we've configured both ends correctly.

The recommendation I received was to switch to a library that didn't require that endpoint (in other words, skip the JWT validation). I'd most likely switch to [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oidc-client); apparently another application is using it successfully.

From what I can tell, the JWKS endpoint is used to verify the authenticity of tokens. Dropping it makes me a little uneasy.

What security risks does this open us up to? Should I push back on this?

Comment: Isn't the JWKS resource on the same server as the OpenID provider, where you do XHR calls to the token endpont anyway?  So it sounds like CORS is just not configured for JWKS. Could it be a reverse proxy error?  Anyway, in the front end, if JWKS and the token resources are served from the same server, you are already verifying the source using TLS, which decreases the risk of not verifying the tokens.  Not a recommended practic, but worth keeping in mind for an overall risk assesment.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I do suspect a reverse proxy misconfigured, but it’s far easier for them to tell me to change then to get someone to actually fix it.

Comment: "I'm updating an Angular SPA application to use OpenID Connect. I found a nice library to help set things up. However, I've run into an issue where it tries to access the JWKS endpoint unsuccessfully; it's **blocked by CORS**": you appear to handle the authentication in the frontend. In many (most?) cases, you want to handle the authentication in the backend instead.

Comment: @ysdx I was unclear at the time. I was updating both the front and backend pieces.

Comment: @ricksmt, if you have a backend, the back-channel calls (including the JWKS call) should be made by the backend. CORS should not impact these.

Answer (score 1):

When using the **authorization code flow**, the ID token is directly received by the client from the Token Endpoint over a secure channel. In this case, **validation of the signature/MAC is [not strictly necessary](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation)** (according to the specification) because the ID token is already authenticated by the TLS layer:

> If the ID Token is received via direct communication between the Client and the Token Endpoint (which it is in this flow), the TLS server validation MAY be used to validate the issuer in place of checking the token signature.

For the **implicit flow**, the signature/MAC [must be validated](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitIDTValidation): **if you skip the verification, the user may forge a malicious ID token**.

However nowadays, the implicit flow is [kind-of deprecated](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#section-2.1.2) anyway in favor with the authorization code flow with PKCE.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID uses JWTs to provide access and ID tokens. These JWTs tell us everything we need to know for those tokens. However, you need to trust the JWT. And to do this you must have the public key available from a source other than the JWT. You can:

1. Get the public key from the JWKS (.well-known/jwks.json) endpoint.
2. Get the public key from some other *trusted* location. This other location can be a database, configuration file, something reasonable.

From the perspective of validating the token, I have not heard of any issue with validating a JWT against a public key found elsewhere.

However, you want to be able to rotate your public key if need be, since the corresponding private key is critical to securing the JWT tokens. If you take option #2, you risk having public keys scattered all over the place that would make it harder to update all the public keys. So if you take route #2 you want to be sure you can rotate your keys.

Also, if the OpenID Connection provider is outside your control, they could change their keys and you wouldn't necessarily know.

The [Signatures and Encryption](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#SigEnc) section of the OpenID spec says:

> The OP advertises its public keys via its Discovery document, or may supply this information by other means. The RP declares its public keys via its Dynamic Registration request, or may communicate this information by other means.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, but their solution is to skip the JWT validation altogether.

Comment: According to the OpenID Connect specs you cannot skip JWT token validation:

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitIDTValidation
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDTokenValidation

Comment: @BartoszRosa Well, he _can_ skip JWT token validation and his application will work; he just won't be compliant with the spec. I'm not recommending it at all, but saying he "cannot" is misleading: there is nothing physically preventing it.

Comment: @DavidS, Yes. Correct. I am not English native ;-) Should be "shouldn't" right ?

Comment: Yes that's right @BartoszRosa. Sorry if I sounded rude: in the tech world I'm using to hearing even native English speakers say something "cannot" be done when what they really mean is "I don't think you should."

Comment: Actually, you can skip signature validation **in the Authorization Code Flow**: "If the ID Token is received via direct communication between the Client and the Token Endpoint (which it is in this flow), the TLS server validation MAY be used to validate the issuer in place of checking the token signature."

Comment: "OpenID uses JWTs to provide access and ID tokens.": No. OpenID uses JWTs for ID Tokens. The access token may be any kind of token. It [may be a JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9068) but it might be any other kind of token.